# PDF rendering issue in wkwebview

Tags: css, angularjs, pdf, wkwebview

I'm having some issues while rendering pdf in multiple tabs in `wkwebview`.
Base64 encoded data is provided as the data for an object tag and that's how pdf is displayed.

**html**

```
<tabset id="receipt-tab" class="pos-relative">
            <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="tabClick(tab.title)">
                <tab-heading>
                    {{ tab.title }}
                </tab-heading>
                <div class="loaddocument">
                    <div class="pdfContainer">
                            <object ng-cloak data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{tab.documentdata}}"
                                width="100%"
                                height="5000"  
                                standby="Loading document...">
                            Oops, you have no PDF viewer enabled
                            </object>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tab>
</tabset>
```

**css**

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height:0px;
}

.tab-content>.active {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    height:450px;
}
```

**Issue**

Multiple PDFs will be displayed in tabs and on initial rendering, the pdf will be rendered properly. But while switching to next tab and coming back to the first one, the pdf gets disappeared and blank screen will be displayed.
This issue is only in WKWebview and not in UI Webview. 
Can anyone suggest the possible reason for this. ?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? Could it be a problem with the visibility CSS?